# LiveServerTestCase does not map Django Application to url

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-testing, django-unittest

### Background:

I am trying to setup my first Selenium driven integration test for a Django app.  I have developed the following simple code:

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class DynamicFormsIntegrationTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.selenium = WebDriver()
        cls.selenium.implicitly_wait(3)
        super(DynamicFormsIntegrationTest, cls).setUpClass()


    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        super(DynamicFormsIntegrationTest, cls).tearDownClass()
        cls.selenium.quit()


    def test_basic(self):
        """ Uses get to open application page """

        self.selenium.get(self.live_server_url + '/woc/')


        #Force Test Fail
        self.fail("FAIL")
```

Now, when I run this test using the following command:

```
python manage.py test test2
```

I get the following output:

```
python manage.py test test2^JCreating test database for alias 'default'...
<QueryDict: {}>
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_basic (test2.tests.test_forms.DynamicFormsIntegrationTest)
Adds a single set via Jquery/Javascript, Submits, and verifies it was rendered and added to Model.Sets
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/path/to/app/test2/tests/test_forms.py", line 42, in test_basic
    self.fail("FAIL")
AssertionError: FAIL

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 8.901s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

And when I run through my regular setup:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get the following output upon page request:

```
python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
September 01, 2013 - 14:42:34
Django version 1.5.1, using settings 'app.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
<QueryDict: {}>
[01/Sep/2013 14:42:39] "GET /test2/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9372
```

As you can see, the web page is not recognized when running the test (& no "GET" request is actually made, as is correctly done in the dev environment request).  I actually believe the "GET" failure is an just an indicator of the problem that the Application is not correctly set up by the LiveServerTestCase.

### Question:

Why is the LiveServerTestCase not recognizing my page urls and how can I resolve the issue?

Comment: The `[01/Sep/2013 14:42:39] "GET /woc/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9372` line is a logger turned on by django when calling `runserver`. It is disabled when running tests. Your view is being run as you can see `<QueryDict: {}>` printed.

Comment: Ah ic - but why then isn't the page output produced after the view is rendered?

Comment: The view's content is rendered in your firefox window.

Comment: It may be true that content is rendered.  But said content is blank and does not match the content expected to be rendered as can be seen when using the development server.